# How to compare time in DB table and the current system time in C#?

Tags: c#, local-database

I need to compare a time in a table with the current system time and need to popup a notification. But how can I compare both?
here is my code and DB:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RestTime FROM FunTime WHERE UserID=1",conn);
String currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");

 if (cmd = currenttime)
 {

 }
```

Comment: You can cast both results to DateTime. Basically here you are trying to compare a SqlCommand object and a String object. also note in your if statement that you are assigning not comparing. Use the double equals operator '=='

Comment: yeah, thats the thing i am lacking, suggest me an idea to compare both? How? plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use`DateTime` directly instead of converting it to `String` and doing string comparisons:

```
 SqlDataReader reader = cmd .ExecuteReader();
 DateTime? dateFromDB = null;
 while (reader.Read())
 {
   dateFromDB  = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["RestTime"]);
 }
 if(dateFromDB.HasValue)
  {
    if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == dateFromDB.TimeOfDay
    {
      // time equal
    }
  }
```

Comment: what was your namespace reference to use "TimeOfDay"?

Comment: it is in `DateTime` class , its under ``System`` namespace